# Row-level cumulative sum with condition

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a table that looks like this.

| m1 | m2 | m3 | m4 | m5 | m6 | m7 | m8 | s |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 5 | 0 | 4 | 10 | 4 |
| 4 | 1 | 8 | 0 | 15 | 0 | 4 | 10 | 10 |

I need to know at which position or column the row-level cumulative sum for the first six columns (`m1 to m6`) either equals or exceeds the value at `s`.

For this table, at row 1, it is 0 + 1 + 0 + 0 + 5 = 6, which is greater than the value at `s` (4); this  occurs at `m5`, or the fifth column from the left, so the expected output is 5.

Similarly, for the second row, it is 4 + 1 + 8 = 13, which is greater than the value at `s` (10); this  occurs at `m3`, or the third column from the left, so the expected output is 3.

The output also needs to be added as a column to the table, so that the final version looks like this:

| m1 | m2 | m3 | m4 | m5 | m6 | m7 | m8 | s | output |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 5 | 0 | 4 | 10 | 4 | 5 |
| 4 | 1 | 8 | 0 | 15 | 0 | 4 | 10 | 10 | 3 |

The table has around 7000 rows. I couldn't figure out a way to use `cumsum()` conditionally, either with pandas or numpy.

Is there a way to accomplish without a loop? (Though loops are ok too)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `cumsum` on `axis=1` with [`get_indexer`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Index.get_indexer.html) on the `df.columns`:

```
df['output'] = df.columns.get_indexer(df.drop("s",1).cumsum(axis=1)
                       .ge(df['s'],axis=0).idxmax(axis=1))+1
```

---

```
print(df)

   m1  m2  m3  m4  m5  m6  m7  m8   s  output
0   0   1   0   0   5   0   4  10   4       5
1   4   1   8   0  15   0   4  10  10       3
```

EDIT:

There can be situations where none of the column in a row satisfies this condition , in that case, you may use a condition to check (*expect a -1 where the condition doesnot match for any column in a row*):

```
c = df.drop("s",1).cumsum(axis=1).ge(df['s'],axis=0)
df['output'] = df.columns.get_indexer(c.idxmax(1).where(c.any(1)))+1
```

Comment: Thanks!! I can understand just about everything here (ge = greater than or equal to) and the final ```+1``` to account for the starts-at-0 factor. Could you elaborate on on the axes and idxmax?

Comment: @H-Finch since each row has a True and False, and idxmax on axis=1 gives the max column name for each row(in case of duplicates it gives the first  col with max value) it would return the name of the column having the first true value